# Converting dates with a format of d/mm/yy (for years earlier than 69)

Tags: r

Converting the character "6/07/69" into a date using the `as.Date` function results in "2068-07-06" instead of "1968-07-06". How can I fix this?

Example:

```
as.Date(c("6/07/68", "6/07/69"), format="%d/%m/%y")
[1] "2068-07-06" "1969-07-06"
```

Comment: Adding a century to year might not be helpful in my case. I have messy data. It is important for me to distinguish cases with and without century within the data.

Comment: Did you read the answers? They give you the methodology to deal with the general problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use library `chron`

e.g.

```
> library(chron)
> as.Date(chron(c("6/07/67", "6/07/69"), format = c(dates = "m/d/y")))
#[1] "1967-06-07" "1969-06-07"
```